# Javascript Skinnable UI Controls Library for Desktop and Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, user-interface

I need something that gives me theming enabled controls (dropdown, combobox, etc), slick animation, dialog windows, and so forth for both desktop and mobile.

The only thing I've found so far is jQuery UI. I'm sure there's more?

Note: I'm not looking for ExtJS or other "big" solutions, just something simple that I can add-on quickly.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a "big" solution (note that things like Ext JS can be trimmed down) then you should use jQuery.

For mobile you should look at using jQuery Touch as well.

Comment: but wouldn't that mean that i'd have to use JQuery UI for the desktop and jQuery touch for the mobile? I'd rather have both devices use the same code base

Comment: jQuery Touch adds gestures and other mobile-related functionality as a jQuery plugin. It would be an additional piece of code, not a replacement, to allow you to add mobile-specific enhancements.